# Нужна ли запятая перед "как"? (2)

Tags: пунктуация

Помогите, пожалуйста, с пунктуацией в комментарии, который сделан к тренировочной программе. Нужна ли запятая перед "как"?

<...>
Жим над головой**
<...>

** - обычно упоминается как "жим стоя".

Answer (score 4):

*...обычно упоминается как "жим стоя".* Запятая в данном случае **не ставится**, поскольку здесь нет сравнения. ***Жим над головой обычно упоминается как жим стоя.*** Имеется в виду, что *жим над головой* обычно упоминается **под названием** *жим стоя.*

*Жим стоя* **не нужно брать в кавычки**, поскольку общепринятые спортивные термины в кавычки не берутся.

Comment: С запятыми разобрались, а почему не нужны кавычки? (интуитивно согласен, но хорошо бы иметь пояснение)

Comment: Это общепринятые спортивные термины, поэтому в кавычки их брать нет причин.